# Error upgrade my Flutter Dart SDK Version

Tags: flutter, dart

I want to upgrade my flutter dart sdk version but I am getting an error as shown below. Is there anyone who can help me with this? Also can I just upgrade to a specific version instead of the top version?

[image]

Answer (score 1):

Try this one

flutter upgrade --force

Comment: this doesn't work

Comment: https://docs.flutter.dev/development/tools/sdk/releases  download here and change env path simple way